# Flick a column positioner

Tags: qt, qml

How do we make a `Positioner` for example a `Column` flickable. 
For example :

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    Column {
        spacing: 2

        Rectangle { color: "red"; width: 50; height: 50 }
        Rectangle { color: "green"; width: 20; height: 50 }
        Rectangle { color: "blue"; width: 50; height: 20 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to at least set the following properties of the `Flickable`:

- `width` and `height` (and/or `anchors`)
- `contentWidth` and `contentHeight`

The following code should do the trick:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    Flickable {
        //anchors.fill: parent
        width: 100
        height: 50
        contentWidth: col.width // you can use whatever you want, this is just an example
        contentHeight: col.height // same here

        Column {
            id: col
            spacing: 2

            Rectangle { color: "red"; width: 50; height: 50 }
            Rectangle { color: "green"; width: 20; height: 50 }
            Rectangle { color: "blue"; width: 50; height: 20 }
        }
    }
}
```